# Dojo equivalent to jQuery.text function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

What is the Dojo equivalent to `$("...").text("asdf")` and `$("...").text()`?

Also is there a wiki or site that provides dojo equivalents of jQuery functions?

Answer (score 3):

A similar function in dojo is NodeList.text()

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/NodeList-manipulate.html#text

You can use like below.

```
dojo.query("#id").text("asdf");
var txt = dojo.query("#id").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [dojo/dom-prop](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dom-prop.html) module.  If you look at the [source](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/dom-prop.js), there is special handling for the textContent property if the current browser does not support it.

```
    if(propName == "textContent" && !has("dom-textContent")) {
        ctr.empty(node);
        node.appendChild(node.ownerDocument.createTextNode(value));
        return node;
    }
```

Your code would look like the following:

```
domProp.set(node, "textContent", "hello world!");
```

or

```
domProp.get(node, "textContent");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append a node to the element:

```
someElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode('asdf'));
```

You also might need to clear it beforehand:

```
while(someElement.firstChild) someElement.removeChild(someElement.firstChild);
```

As for getting the text, I don't know if there's a direct equivalent but you probably won't need one. Just read the `nodeValue` of the element's `firstChild`.

Answer (score -1):

Use can do this as

```
dojo.query('#yourdiv')[0].lastChild.textContent = 'text';
var text = dojo.query('#yourdiv')[0].lastChild.textContent
```

Comment: Will this work in IE and Chrome as well? I thought textContent was only FF and innerText was IE and Chrome?  This is why I am looking for a cross-browser jquery.text solution.

Comment: @Derek, Yes, this is work from IE 9 Onwards and Chrome onwards.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it could be because `textContent` isn't available in IE < 9.